# Empty result scrape using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am Scraping data using BeautifulSoup but getting an empty result when selecting any tag, here is my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}

boardgame_url = "https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/285961/heaven-ale-kegs-more"
page = requests.get(boardgame_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')

product_title = soup.select('h1 a')
print(product_title)
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/I8Gdtja you can view in this image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some dynamic contents are not rendered when scraping with `BeautifulSoup`. What you're seeing in browser vs what your scraper is getting is markedly different. (You can export page.content and compare). You'll need a different module like `selenium` or `request-html` that can handle dynamic contents

If you want some data from the web-page then you can get the java-script variable and extract data according to your need.
You can go through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283742/getting-javascript-variable-value-while-scraping-with-python) in stack-overflow for further help

Comment: Looks like it is dynamic website content is being loaded from API using JS. I have printed soup but it is different from what in see in the browser. Will selenium solve this issue?

Comment: Yes selenium will solve this as it is uses browser which will render the javascript and you can get the html document then